# Trying to keep slugs unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unique, slug

I posted a question similar to this before and it was suggested that I use friendlyIds gem however it was not for me as I had some real issues with it. Moving swiftly on...

I'm trying to create URL's where it points to **whatever.com/first_name-second_name**
I've got that working **but** it does not account for when people sign up with the same name.

I found this code online and to me it seems pretty sound - my generate_slug method is within my user_controller but when ever I attempt to sign up to my app again I get the error;

**NoMethodError in UsersController#create
undefined method `user' for #**

**Here's the generate_slug method;**

```
  def generate_slug
  if user(:slug => full_name.parameterize).count > 0
    n = 1
    while user(:slug => "#{full_name.parameterize}-#{n}").count > 0
      n += 1
    end
    self.slug= "#{full_name.parameterize}-#{n}"
  else
    self.slug = full_name.parameterize
  end
end
```

**And heres the users#create;**

```
  def create 
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:sessions][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password])
      if params[:remember_me]
        cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
      else
        cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
      end
      redirect_to users_show_path(current_user), notice: "Logged in"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid."
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with this? I've tried various things and hacking away at it but I'm very new to rails and not sure of what I'm doing wrong here.

Any help or pointers is much appreciated,

Thanks for your time!

**Edit**

**1 - Here is the full trace;**

```
activemodel (3.2.10) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
app/models/user.rb:38:in `generate_slug'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__4251811508524484974__create__672836159521965693__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_create_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:268:in `create'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:348:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `block in create_or_update'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__4251811508524484974__save__672836159521965693__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:84:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block in save'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:258:in `save'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:10:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__1712494193629644471__process_action__997902979293854086__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.10) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__4266248573959168775__call__672836159521965693__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.10) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.10) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.10) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.10) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.10) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.10) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.10) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.10) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

**2 -** The generate_slug is being created in a before_create in the user model

**3 -** I was having some issues with that as well - it seems to be very temperamental - As you said I tried to change to user but that didn't work - however current_user doesn't work any more - I'll look into that just now

**4 -** No I'm not using an authentication gem - I'm just using this to try and learn some rails and the theory behind it so I'm trying to stay clear of gems :)

Answer (score 0):

We need some more background.

1. The error is incomplete. Please provide us the full trace.
2. Where is `generate_slug` called from? In a `before_create` of model User?
3. You are calling `current_user` in the `redirect_to` on the `create` method. Why not the `user` variable you have definied previously?
4. Are you using an authentication gem, like Devise or Clearance?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this - I've updated the question with what you've asked at the bottom :)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easy to add `user_id` into the slug?

```
def generate_slug
  "#{id}-#{full_name.parameterize}"
end
```

Comment: @ckg3g - what I'm trying to do is not use the ID of the user but count the number of users with the same full_name and then if none exist have the name as first_name-second_name and if one or more exist have them as first_name_last_name_number - with number being the instance of the person so they whouldnt get hugely long and hard to remember with a large user base - thanks for taking the time too look over this for me though! :)

Comment: @Jamie but you are doing extra queries for checking. My solution leads to avoid extra queries.